# Git Bash not remembering the home I set

Tags: command-line, terminal, git-bash

I want my home directory to be c:\USERS\TONY so I did this command `HOME=$USERPROFILE` and when i `echo` it and it gives me the wanted result. However, when I shut down my computer and come back the next day it goes back to what it was before. How do i set it permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add that `HOME` variable as a [USER environment variable](https://superuser.com/q/949560/141) in your Windows settings

That way, any git bash session will consider that folder as your HOME.

But a Git for Windows does already that for USERPROFILE: it already is $HOME.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to do that using the command line?

Comment: @Tony It is a one-timle operation that will persists across reboots. Doing it in command-line is [possible using `setx`](https://superuser.com/a/803122/141).